# What do you call a person who works with statistics?

Tags: single-word-requests

I mean person who administrates something is called administrator. Person who manages something is called manager. How to call a person who works with statistics?

Comment: I don't think your line of reasoning is quite right. A manager doesn't "work with managing", but you would have gotten it if you said that "a mathematician works with math"

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=one+who+works+with+statistics&aq=f&oq=one+who+works+with+statistics&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j0j60l2.3782&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: TIKSN, the "how to call" wording is incorrect in English. You should replace the *how* with *what*. You would benefit from reading the discussion at this link http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150325/how-do-we-call-something-in-english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One calls him or her a "statistician."

Comment: Could TIKSN not find this in a dictionary?  Or is EL&U now so well-established that one comes here *before* a dictionary?  If so, it seems to have worked.

Comment: @GEdgar I would really like to know how to look up a word of which I only know the meaning. You know, as a English learner, I often don't know how to express myself because I can't find a suitable phrase.

Comment: In this case, look in the dictionary near the entry "statistics" to find related words.